# If condition not working on operator 'equal' and working on assignment operator

Tags: php

Hello I have a strange problem in which my If statement is not working. I am doing a simple user registration and would like to check if the variable 'sendmail' is equal to 1, to send an e-mail if not to not send e-mail. I have shorten the mail function code for better understanding:

```
$usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );
/* check if the password is the same */
if( $_POST['password'] == $_POST['conpassword'] && $_POST['email'] == $_POST['emailconfirm'] ) {

/* Check if the sendmail variable is equal to 1 */  
if ($POST['sendmail'] == 1){
/* send e-mail function the */

mail($to,$email_subject,nl2br($email_body),$headers);   

}
echo $usr->register($_POST);
```

So the problem is that the condition in this case  `if ($POST['sendmail'] == 1)` is not working, and it is not sending the e-mail. In case if I write it like this  if `($POST['sendmail'] = 1)` this way is working no matter what argument the variable sendmail have inside it, it is always sending the e-mail.

this is from where `sendmail` is coming

```
<select name="sendmail"> 
<option  value="0">No</option>
<option  value="1">Yes</option> 
</select>
```

I've checked the post array and the variable sendmail is inside so this can't be the problem.
Any help will be very welcome. Thank you.

Comment: `$POST['sendmail']` should be `$_POST['sendmail']`.

Comment: What @RocketHazmat said. [**Enable error reporting**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) to discover such errors easily.

Comment: @AmalMurali Excellent point! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$POST['sendmail'] == 1
```

should be:

```
$_POST['sendmail'] == 1
```

Doing assignment instead of comparison is not what you want.

```
$_POST['sendmail'] = 1
```

is *truthy* because the value being assigned (`1`) is truthy. If you did `if ($var = 0)` instead it would never pass.

You should also consider using `===`. This works if you know the type of both variables. `$_POST` input is always strings, so:

```
$_POST["sendmail"] === "1"
```

Comment: "*Doing assignment instead of comparison is not what you want.*" — Where in this code does he *assign* a value?

Comment: Read his original question. He mentions changing the comparison for assignment.

Comment: okay I fixed the $_POST, if I use == it is sending every time the e-mails no mater what is choosen if I use === it is not sending anything never.

Comment: That makes no sense. Is the value of `$_POST["sendmail"]` `"1"`, `"0"` or something else?

Comment: this is the problem, this is the result of the post array in case If I choose no: ["sendmail"]=> string(1) "0"

Comment: Well, then it shouldn't send the email, right? This is expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($POST['sendmail'] == 1){
```

Should be

```
if ($_POST['sendmail'] == 1){
```